# Airplane mode in Android

Tags: android

In AirplaneModEnabler.java present in ..\packages\apps\Settings\src\com\android\settings, the handler looks for EVENT_SERVICE_STATE_CHANGED to toggle the state of the checkbox and to display the summary.

When and from where is EVENT_SERVICE_STATE_CHANGED triggered? Currently the airplane mode functionality is very weird. I need to debug from the point where this event is triggered.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

-Webgenius